How to use "wish" with past tenses
Can we use past simple with "wish" to refer to the future or only to the present and repeated events? For instance

I wish you gave me a hand when we get there

Is it possible that this means "he won't help me once we are there" or "every time we are there he doesn't help"?
Ps. On this site  https://www.eslbase.com/grammar/wish I found this example "I wish you weren’t leaving tomorrow". So it must be true that past tenses with "wish" can also refer to future not only to present events?
Can anyone else comment because currently two people give me different answers

I. Simple Past or Hypothetical sentence?
OP's two sentences are:

1."I wish you gave me a hand when we get there".
2."I wish you weren’t leaving tomorrow"

The past tense verbs 'gave' and 'weren't leaving' in these sentences are used to express hypothetical or unlikely future situations  and they are not showing simple past actions. These sentences are examples of Elliptical Second Conditionals with implied main clauses, which can be completed as:

"I wish you gave me a hand when we get there, but you won't."
"I wish you weren’t leaving tomorrow, but you will."

II. Does it imply repeated action?

Is it possible that this means "he won't help me once we are there" or "every time we are there he doesn't help"?

The present construction shows hypothetical situation. To make it clear that you mean "every time", you can add every time or whenever in the sentence.
."I wish you gave me a hand whenever we're in this situation."
Edit-1.
As OP has edited the post. I am providing further clarifications:
The sentences:
1."I wish you gave me a hand when we get there.".
2."I wish you weren’t leaving tomorrow."

Why the sentences are considered Second Conditional ?.
The "I wish" clause implies the condition "If there were possible" or "If this could happen". The main clauses are implied as discussed earlier.

Why these sentences describe one-time future events, not repeated actions.



"When we get there" implies reaching a specific destination (one place).
"Tomorrow" indicates a specific day (next day only).

If you consider this sentence:
"I wish you gave me a hand when I wash the dishes.".
This implies a repeated action, because "when I wash the dishes" is a routine or habitual activity.
Sharing the link of a site explaining the Second Conditional using "I wish...."

Ref.lingbase.com..
So, if we speak about the present or the future (= the second conditional), then the sentence has the following structure:
I wish ... + past simple.
https://lingbase.com/en/english/grammar/wish#:~:text=%22I%20wish%22%20in%20the%20conditionals&text=We%20say%20%22I%20wish%22%20%2B,be%20great%20if%20I%20did.


When you use the past tense with "wish", it's used to refer to repeating activities that are expected to continue. So your sentence means that you wish that every time we get there, the other person would give you a hand. It also suggests that this hasn't been happening in the past, so you're wishing for a change in the future.
If you're talking about a specific upcoming event, you use the conditional form:

I wish you would give me a hand when we get there.

